# Slow evaluation of sum of Binomials

Tags: plotting, summation

I am trying to use DiscretePlot on the expression shown below, but my system is taking surprisingly long to complete the task. In fact, after 15 minutes, its still working. I would have thought the expression is simple enough. Why the long delay?[image]

Comment: Please post code in properly formatted code blocks instead of as images in your post.

Comment: But I ca see one problem: `[1-p]` should be `(1-p)` near the end of the definitions of `alpha`.

Comment: This was indeed a simple mistake. I apologize for the simple syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

As `march` points out, the whole issue is the incorrect use of square brackets instead of parens.  Square brackets are for function application only.

For example,

```
α[j_] := Sum[
    Binomial[(c + t)/2, k] Binomial[(c - t)/2, (c + j)/2 - k] 
    p^(2 k - (j + t)/2) (1 - p)^(c - (2 k - (j + t)/2)), 
    {k, Max[0, (j + t)/2], Min[(c + j)/2, (c + t)/2]}
    ]

DiscretePlot[α[j], {j, -9, 9, 2}]
```

yields
[image]
instantly.

Comment: I am sorry for the trivial mistake! Thank you for your solution.